# Calling SQL Server stored procedure in VB

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a SQL Server stored procedure based on my previous question that I asked which was answered that is why I am creating a new question.

STORED PROCEDURE

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[usp_validatecard](
@CLUBCARD1 nvarchar(50),
@STATUS nvarchar(50))
As

BEGIN
IF EXISTS(Select CLUBCARD1, STATUS
from dbo.clubmembers 
where CLUBCARD1 = @CLUBCARD1 and STATUS = 'ACTIVE')
Print 'Card is GOOD'
ELSE
IF EXISTS(SELECT CLUBCARD1, STATUS
FROM dbo.clubmembers
where CLUBCARD1 = @CLUBCARD1 and STATUS = 'INACTIVE')
PRINT 'Card is good but not active'
ELSE
PRINT 'CARD NOT IN SYSTEM'
END
```

The trouble I am having is not too sure how to call that in VB. The code I have so far is this

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Configuration
Imports System.Data

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub cmdclick_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdclick.Click
        Dim strConnString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("orca").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("usp_validatecard", con)
        cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CLUBCARD1", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtvalidate.Text

        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim Result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            lblmessage.Text = "Error"
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

What I am trying to do is if the clubcard parameter is found and status is active I would like the label to read 'card is good' also if the clubcard parameter is found however is inactive then the label should read 'card is good but not active' last if all those fail just have the label read 'card not in system'

As of right now this code does not work I thought I could just call the stored procedure and exec it and it would print the statements depending on what passes however it is erroring out.

When I debug it the error I get is under the cmd.parameters.add is

> Item In order to evaluate an indexed
>   property, the property must be
>   qualified and the arguments must be
>   explicitly supplied by the user.

Comment: Can you remove `@STATUS nvarchar(50)` parameter from your stored procedure? Doesn't look like it's being used and is not set in your vb.net code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your SP to

```
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(Select CLUBCARD1, STATUS
from dbo.clubmembers 
where CLUBCARD1 = @CLUBCARD1 and STATUS = 'ACTIVE')
Print 'Card is GOOD'
Select 'Card is GOOD'; 
ELSE
IF EXISTS(SELECT CLUBCARD1, STATUS
FROM dbo.clubmembers
where CLUBCARD1 = @CLUBCARD1 and STATUS = 'INACTIVE')
PRINT 'Card is good but not active'
Select 'Card is good but not active'; 
ELSE
PRINT 'CARD NOT IN SYSTEM'
Select 'CARD NOT IN SYSTEM'; 
END
```

and  in vb.net side,

```
Dim reader as SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
If reader.Read() Then
    lblmessage.Text = Convert.ToString(reader(0))
End If
```

Comment: Hello bala i removed the @status but I am getting a compilation error from the lblmessage.text = convert.tostring(reader[0]) says "identifier expected" The vb.net code you gave me i added it in place of my try catch not sure if that is correct Thanks

Comment: @Jawaid it should be `reader(0)` and not `reader[0]`. I didn't translate it very well from c# the first time.

Comment: thanks that worked great do you mine explaining why that fixed it. What is the reader(0) actually doing?

Comment: When you do `Select 'Card is GOOD';` in the stored procedure, it returns a structure like a table with 1 row and 1 column, if you will. reader(0) ( reader[0] in c#) gets the value from the first column of the current row.  `reader.Read()` advances the row pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the result back from the stored procedure.

Print doesn't return anything, it just prints within SQL Server (useful for when running a stored procedure within management studio).

You need to define the @STATUS parameter within your code as an output parameter (define the parameter with an empty string then set parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output).

Then in the stored procedure, rather than printing, you need to say SET @STATUS= string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sp in your database:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[usp_validatecard](
@strCLUBCARD1 nvarchar(50)
)
As
 SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN EXISTS(SELECT CLUBCARD1, [STATUS] FROM dbo.clubmembers WHERE CLUBCARD1 = @strCLUBCARD1 AND [STATUS] = 'ACTIVE') THEN 'CARD IS GOOD'
      WHEN EXISTS(SELECT CLUBCARD1, [STATUS] FROM dbo.clubmembers WHERE CLUBCARD1 = @strCLUBCARD1 AND [STATUS] = 'INACTIVE') THEN 'CARD IS GOOD BUT NOT ACTIVE'
      ELSE 'CARD NOT IN SYSTEM'
    END
```

... and then this in your data factory:

```
''' <summary>
''' Validates a card in the database
''' </summary>
''' <param name="clubCard">The card to validate</param>
Public Shared Function ValidateCard(ByVal clubCard As String) As String

    'create connection
    Using cnSQL As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("MyConnectionString")
        Using cmdSP As New SqlCommand("usp_validatecard", cnSQL)
            cmdSP.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

            'declare and add  parameter
            cmdSP.Parameters.Add("@strCLUBCARD1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = clubCard

            Dim dtTable As New DataTable

            'execute command
            Try
                cnSQL.Open()
                dtTable.Load(cmdSP.ExecuteReader())
                cnSQL.Close()
            Catch ex As SqlException
                'do something here
            End Try

            'return string
            Return dtTable.Rows(0)(0)
        End Using
    End Using

End Function
```